# Logging in a website with POST data using wget or curl

Tags: php, html, curl, authentication, wget

I am trying to figure out how to format my post data correctly for this particular website that has the following parameters for its login, password, and login button:

USERNAME HTML LINE:

`<input class="auth-input" type="text" name="j_username" placeholder="e.g. joe@email.com">`

PASSWORD HTML LINE:

`<input class="auth-input" name="j_password" type="password" id="contra">`

LOGIN BUTTON HTML LINE:

`<input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn_action" style="width: 100px;" title="Anouncements" value="Log In">`

For wget, I can use the `data='username=blah&password=blah&submit=blah'` and for curl I can use the '-d' option the exact same way and I already know it should be percent encoded.

For some reason I can't figure out the right combination that should be the correct parameters for the POST data.

I'm using `data='j_username=myUsername&j_password=myPassword&submit=Log%20In'` which I believe to be correct, but it is not working. What am I missing here? Should I be using the "name" part instead, or the "type," etc.?

Comment: Use a network sniffer to compare your attempts with a working request sent by a browser.

Comment: @arkascha ok I'm going to install wireshark and check the output.

Comment: So it looks like my keys are correct with j_username and j_password, but I see 2 things different than what I initially thought was correct:

1) Part of the temporary password I'm using has a * and ! in it. It is percent encoding the ! to %21, which is expected, but it is NOT percent encoding the * and leaving it as plain text. 

2) The space between "Log In" is not percent encoded either, but rather has this format - `Log+ In`

I'm going to try a few more test runs in my script and see if I can nail it down.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please follow these steps. And also create cookies.txt file with write permission in the directory of the script. Also please replace the username/pass and url from actual .
`

```
//The username or email address of the account.
define('USERNAME', 'sdfg@sfg.com');

//The password of the account.
define('PASSWORD', 'rterty');

//Set a user agent. This basically tells the server that we are using Chrome 
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');

//Where our cookie information will be stored (needed for authentication).
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');

//URL of the login form.
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'https://www.example.com/index.php');

//Login action URL. Sometimes, this is the same URL as the login form.
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'https://www.example.com/login.php');


//An associative array that represents the required form fields.
//You will need to change the keys / index names to match the name of the form
//fields.
$postValues = array(
    'email' => USERNAME,
    'userPass' => PASSWORD
);

//Initiate cURL.
$curl = curl_init();

//Set the URL that we want to send our POST request to. In this
//case, it's the action URL of the login form.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);

//Tell cURL that we want to carry out a POST request.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//Set our post fields / date (from the array above).
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));

//We don't want any HTTPS errors.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Where our cookie details are saved. This is typically required
//for authentication, as the session ID is usually saved in the cookie file.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

//Sets the user agent. Some websites will attempt to block bot user agents.
//Hence the reason I gave it a Chrome user agent.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

//Tells cURL to return the output once the request has been executed.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Allows us to set the referer header. In this particular case, we are 
//fooling the server into thinking that we were referred by the login form.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);

//Do we want to follow any redirects?
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    //Execute the login request.
curl_exec($curl);

//Check for errors!
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}else{
    //do actions
}
```

`